# Remote sharing doesn't work even after allowing config in Firewall

Tags: network, remote-desktop, firewall, remote-control

I've allowed remote sharing in the Firewall

[image]

And enabled remote sharing and remote login.

[image]

I have Observe and Control enabled from the options dialog in Remote sharing.

But remote sharing works only when I turn off the firewall; else connection times out. Both the machines MacBook Pro m1 where I enabled this and iMac from where I'm trying to connect are in my home network connected to same wifi SSID.

SSH works.

Comment: Try enabling Remote Apple Events & changing from name.local or .dlink to an actual IP address.

Comment: Cool - tbh I don't know why that actually would 'make it work' I just looked at what I have set in my Sharing setup